# C++ Как для переменной обозначить целую папку с данными

Tags: c++, переменные

есть вопрос, как для переменной argd присвоить папку с 600+ файлами, если это конечно возможно. после того как переменной присвояться все файлы из папки она будет работать так:
если файл загруженный пользоваетелем совпадает со списком в переменной argd то продолжается работа, если нет, ошибка. пока точно не знаю как расписать в коде эту if, надеюсь достаточно понятно обьяснил.

Буду благодарен каждому ответу.

Comment: Я бы хранил список файлов как `std::set<std::string>`, и заполнял его через `std::directory_iterator`.

Comment: Вы собираетесь хранить только имена файлов или еще и их содержимое?

Comment: @avp Я буду хранить только имена с их форматом. По типу "ABCCBA.txt"

Comment: Тогда не очень понятно, **зачем вообще** их хранить. Можно ведь просто для каждого загружаемого файла спрашивать у ОС, есть ли такое имя в папке.

Comment: Там идёт работа с DLL, и в коде который я нашёл прописана только одна DLL-ка у меня таких 642 и мне нужно чтобы программа работала для каждой, вот я и подумал почему-бы не попробовать сделать список в котором я просто собрал навания всех DLL

Comment: Я думал и о таком методе который в описали, но как я не пытался его сделать были вечные ошибки

Comment: *"Я думал и о таком методе который в описали, но как я не пытался его сделать были вечные ошибки"* - это не повод отказываться от нормального решения в пользу неэффективного...

Comment: @Harry Я не смог этого сделать и решил просто поискать варианты:)